# What happens if a genitive relative pronoun has to be declined?

Tags: word-usage, relative-clause

The best explanation is with an example:

> Ich habe ihm gesagt, dass ....

"Er" becomes "ihm" in the dative.

If we have a "normal" relative pronoun, then we get

> Der Mann, dem ich gesagt habe, dass ...

"Der" becomes "dem" in the dative. So far so good.

But what happens if we have a genitive relative, eg

> Der Mann, ??? dessen Sohn ich gesagt habe, dass ...

We'd have to "decline" "dessen" in the dative, but is there such a thing? Are we then forced to put a "zu" in the ??? part? Or does the pronoun become "dessem" (I think not)? Or yet something else?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/how-to-say-of-which/6859#6859

Comment: strongly related but German: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17965/relativpronomen-welcher-im-genitiv/17968#17968

Comment: Those aren't exactly too relevant since the OP obviously knows you can use _dessen_ in this case. He's asking something else

Comment: @Carlen ah that's more like it! I read your comment too late and already wrote an answer. I guess it's okay since that thread is in English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is that *dessen* isn't the word that needs to be declined. It's *Sohn*.

Now to explain why, we need to think about their roles.

- dessen: depicts the genitive as a relative pronoun. This could just as easily be a noun in the Genitive case in a normal clause.
- Sohn: the actual object of the relative clause, i.e. the person you actually told something.

Since *Sohn* is the person you actually told it to, it's the noun that should be in the Dative case. This is hidden in this sentence but would be visible if there was an adjective or if it was a plural form.

> Der Mann, dessen ältestem Sohn ich gesagt habe, [...]
>
> Der Mann, dessen Kindern ich gesagt habe, [...]

In short, you don't decline *dessen* because that's already a relative pronoun in its declined form, so to speak. You decline the actual object, but that won't be visible under certain circumstances.